# How to update a record with unchecked checkboxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three rows of checkboxes on frontend side

[image]

when I check some values and then pass on the parameters to controller, they look like numbers. For example,

```
"service_attributes"=>{"id"=>1, "simplicity"=>"1", "convenience"=>"3", "atmosphere"=>"5"}
```

Every time I change a value on any of the row, the record gets updated, however when I uncheck options, params are not being passed

```
"service_attributes"=>{"id"=>1}
```

and nothing happens. The record remains with old values.

How can I do so that when I uncheck the checkboxes, the record is supposed to update with 0 values. Like the following:

```
<Service id: 1, simplicity: 0, convenience: 0, atmosphere: 2, user_id: 1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another field that will pass the value false to your controller.

```
<input name="service_attributes[simplicity]" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="service_attributes_ simplicity" name="service_attributes[simplicity]" value="1" />
```

Or you could simply use the [checkbox_helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box).

Comment: Thank you, Jeremie!

Comment: Glad I could help!